# sql match pattern regex query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have regex pattern:

```
Regex: \d+(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)\s+?(.+)?word(.+)?
```

and I have a table which has subtitle_content column; for example, I have some records like the following example:

```
1
00:00:10,770 --> 00:00:12,670
CHECK YOUR EMAIL FOR THE SECOND MISSION

2
00:00:14,540 --> 00:00:15,740
READ IT ALONE word

3
00:00:45,940 --> 00:00:47,640
WANTED - SECOND word MISSION
```

I want to send this regex pattern with my SQL query, my query bring all the content of subtitle,but which query should I use to return only the row of subtitle_content which matches to this regex? 
in this condition I want to return :

```
00:00:14,540 --> 00:00:15,740
READ IT ALONE word

00:00:45,940 --> 00:00:47,640
WANTED - SECOND word MISSION
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_name where subtitle_content REGEXP "Regular Expression Here"
```

Comment: thanks , but this query will return all record contain "Regular Expression Here" ... and i want return just rows of record that that contain  this "Regular Expression Here"